# Rapidly open new tabs and randomly navigate with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm designing some tests to run against a network filter and came up with the edge case of a lot of traffic reaching the filter at once. I know that in Selenium I can find a random link on a page (link selector + a random number) and use this to go to another page. However, is there a way I can do this for 50 tabs at once? The point of the test is to open 50 tabs and randomly navigate around the links on each page to simulate a heavier-than-usual load (the number may vary, example only).

So far all I've been able to come up with is a short loop that will open 50 tabs through JavaScript, and then move through the tabs individually and navigate elsewhere.

```
@Test(timeout=1000000)
public void testHeavyUsageTraffic() throws Exception {
    driver.get("http://**********.com");
    Random rand = new Random();
    WebElement randomLinkGenerator = driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));

    //Open several tabs to simulate increased load
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("for (i = 0; i< 50;i++) { document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click(); }");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.print("\nIteration " + (i + 1));
        for (String window : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            //Switch to the next window and click the link to generate a random url request
            driver.switchTo().window(window);
            System.out.print("\n" + driver.getTitle());
            List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            System.out.print(" - # of Links: " + links.size());

            //If no links are found on the page, skip to the next window
            if (links.size() <= 0) {
                driver.close();
                continue;
            }

            //Randomly choose a link from the page and open it
            int randomInt = rand.nextInt(links.size());
            System.out.print(" - #" + randomInt + " was randomly chosen");

            try {
                links.get(randomInt).click();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print(" - Link was not clickable");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    //TODO: REMOVE THIS
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    //Check for filtered traffic here...
    //assert(checkFilteredTraffic("http://filtered-site.com"));
}
```

However, this is extremely slow. The original opening of 50 tabs is extremely quick (JavaScript) but the Java for switching between tabs and selecting a link is very slow. I am assuming that this is to do with either the Chrome driver or simply how Selenium handles multiple windows.

Does anyone know how to better handle this? To reiterate, I want to be able to simulate a heavy network load, and then at the end check for a filtered site to ensure that it can't slip by while the system is under more load than usual.

**EDIT:** I am aware of load testing mechanisms, but this test is supposed to be included in the Selenium Test Cases.

Let me know if I should include anything else. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a job for a load test. Have you considered doing one?

Comment: @JeffC Edited the question to include this. Yes, I have considered this but am supposed to keep it inside Selenium.